# Is it possible to open a flatfile in PLSQL when only a partial filename is known?

Tags: file, plsql, wildcard

Is it possible to open a flatfile when only part of the file name is known?

I have files in a directory that have a timestamp appended to the filename, is it possible to open it by specifiying the known part of the filename (excluding timestamp)?

Is it possible with a PLSQL only approach?

Answer (score 1):

There is a dbms_ package which allows you to get a directory listing for the directory (or you can implement your own in a java stored procedure - google!) This will allow you to find the file you are looking for - if necessary choose which is the relevant file and then process.

See http://notdennis.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/listing-directory-files-plsql/